# Chart js assign default value for y axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have the following line Chart:
X axis : date
Y axis : 0, 1, 2.

```
 var lineChartData = {
                labels : data_grafico,
                datasets : [
                    {
                            fillColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                            strokeColor : "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
                            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            bezierCurve : false,
                            label: "Cassa",
                            data : cassa
                    },
                    {
                            fillColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                            highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                            highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            bezierCurve : false,
                            label: "Bar",
                            data : bar
                    }
                ]
            };
```

Cassa and Bar looks like : [0,0,1,2,0 ... ]
Obviously if i don't have any 2 value it isn't on the y axis.
How can i always have my 0,1,2 on the y axis even if there isn't any line with that value?
And then what if i want to change 0,1,2 with some word "zero", "one", "two"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scaleOverride` and `scaleLabel` options, like so

```
new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: 2,
    scaleStepWidth: 1,
    scaleStartValue: 0,
    scaleLabel: function(d) {
      switch(d.value) {
        case "0": return 'zero';
        case "1": return 'one';
        case "2": return 'two';
      }
    },
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zh4c58p6/